# Javascript button to update record and load webpage

Tags: javascript

I can't understand why this Javascript button doesn't work.

I keep getting an error: "Invalid or unexpected token"

Can anyone see why this is?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/39.0/connection.js")}

var records = [];

var opp = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
    opp.Id = "{!Opportunity.Id}";

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
    }

opp.Docusign_Send_Date__c = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

var result = sforce.connection.update([records]);

if(result[0].success === "true"){
    window.location = '/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}';
}
else{
    alert(
        "An Error has Occurred. Error: " +
        result[0].errors.message
    );
}
}

catch(e){
    alert(
      "An unexpected Error has Occurred. Error: " + e
      );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there is an extra brace( } ) after your else statement. You also need a try to go along with the catch.

Comment: Not sure how I didn't spot that! Thanks so much! Sometimes it's the simple things.